# Dynamic angular-strap modal template content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I want to get angular-strap modal content through a http service and after completion of service create a dynamic html content on basis of response, and show this content in modal.
In short need an event on which i can able to get modal content and than show that fetched content.

For ex i have a list of user, on click on user name i need to fetch that corresponding user details from server and after completion of service i need to show user profile in modal.

I tried below code for li creation and on click of each li i need a different model, which is fetched from server

```
<li ng-repeat="category in subCategories" id="{{category.id}}" ng-class="getCategoryIndex(category) != -1 ? 'inactive' : 'active';"  ng-click="select_subCategory();"
                data-template="questions.html" data-placement="center" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" bs-modal="modal"
            >
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> {{category.name}}<div class="checkbox cross"><input type="checkbox" id="box_{{category.id}}" /><label for="box_{{category.id}}"></label></div>
            </li>
```

Where questions.html is a static template and will be working fine for static template but how i will make it to be fetched from server as per li heading ?

Static Template Loads as :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="questions.html">
    ...
</script>
```

How to make template as per clicked li ?

Comment: I had similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in angular motion we can directly able to change ng-bind objects in a manner shown below :

```
$scope.change_content = function(){

      $scope.aside = {title: 'Custom Title', content: 'Hello Custom Aside<br />This content can be fetched through an ajax request!'};
      $scope.modal = {title: 'Custom Title', content: 'Hello Custom Modal<br />This content can be fetched through an ajax request!'};
      var el = document.getElementById('trigger');
      angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');
  };
```